# MUI CheckBox fill color when the box is unticked

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a requirement to show checkboxes like below when there is no check.

[image]

When the user marks the checkbox it should be like this

[image]

The second thing I already achieved with this code

```
 <Checkbox
        sx={{
          color: "#DFE0EB",
          // backgroundColor: "#DFE0EB",
          "&.Mui-checked": {
            color: "#1DFB9D"
          }
        }}
      />
```

But when the user doesn't mark the checkbox how can I fill it with this color #DFE0EB

[This is my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-shannon-2csy8u)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this out and it seems you can not directly change the background color because Mui is using an icon to display the empty checkbox (tried with Mui: 5.10.5). The good news is that you can customize the icon used for the empty checkbox and pass a fill color to that icon. Unfortunatly it seems that Mui does not have an icon of a filled square (as far as I can see), and you would have to use a different icon library for that. Changing the empty checkbox icon can be done like this. Nice to know is that you can also change the checkedIcon like this.

```
<Checkbox
    sx={{
        color: "#DFE0EB",
        "&.Mui-checked": {
            color: "#1DFB9D"
        }
    }}
    icon={<SquareIconHere style={{fill: '#DFE0EB'}}>}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a custom icon:

```
const CheckBoxBlankIcon = () => (
  <SvgIcon>
    <svg focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" data-testid="CheckBoxBlankIcon">
      <path
        d="M19 3H5c-1.11 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h14c1.11 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.89-2-2-2zm-9 14l-5-5"
        fill="white"
      ></path>
    </svg>
  </SvgIcon>
);

<Checkbox icon={<CheckBoxBlankIcon />} />
```